# Is Making dependencies manually always semantically equivalent to specifying dependencies?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

Consider a Makefile that looks like the following:

```
A: B C
   # Do stuff to build A

B:
   # Do stuff to build B

C:
   # Do stuff to build C
```

Is this always semantically equivalent to the following Makefile, for all values of A, B, and C?

```
A:
   make B C
   # Do stuff to build A

B:
   # Do stuff to build B

C:
   # Do stuff to build C
```

Comment: I would say, no in general. Because `make A` could be called with additional parameters or environment, which you would not pass through in `make B C`.

Comment: No. In the first case `A` is rebuilt if [it is needed] **and** [[it does not exist]  **or** [it exists but it is older than `B` or `C` or both]]. In the second case `A` is rebuilt if [it is needed] **and** [it does not exist]. So, if `A` and `B` exist and `A` is older than `B`, in the first case `make A` rebuilds `A` while in the second case `make A` simply prints `make: 'A' is up to date.`